# Laravel Vue SPA Sourcemaps not showing original lines

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, single-page-application, laravel-mix

I'm working with a Laravel / VUE Single-Page Application and am having difficulties debugging using source maps. Currently, errors are reported like the following (using Chrome)

[image]

The files here have correct line numbers but contain compiled code. Is this the expected behavior? I would like to see the true source code for debugging purposes. Here is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
    devtool: 'eval-source-map'
});


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```